# Can i configure a remote DOCKER_HOST using the spotify plugin similar to farbic8

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, amazon-ec2, spotify

OS: Windows 10, 
Docker Daemon : Running on EC2 instance, 
Spring-Boot Docker Project : On local machine.

What i am trying to achieve using docker-maven-spotify plugin

- I Do not have docker daemon runnning on my OS (which i know is possible) but am trying to make use of Docker running on my EC2 machine.
- When i try to run the step "mvn install dockerfile:build" it is looking for Docker on my local machine, but it want it make use of docker running on my EC2 and build the docker image.

Could you please help me with some suggestions as to how can i configure the DOCKER_HOST using the spotify-maven plugin.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin#setup), you just need to define the environment variable:

> By default the plugin will try to connect to docker on `localhost:2375`. Set the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable to connect elsewhere.
>
> ```
> DOCKER_HOST=tcp://<host>:2375
> ```
>
> Other docker-standard environment variables are honored too such as TLS and certificates.

Note: It really has to be an environment variable; passing via `-DDOCKER_HOST` to Maven doesn't work.